# How to generate CLSID GUID while Registering icon overlay handlers in windows?

Tags: c++, overlay, windows-shell

I am using  [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144123(v=vs.85).aspx) for refernce to generate overlay icons in windows. But I am not getting what is `MyOverlay CLSID GUID`? I need to create a key in `Registry` and set a `CLSID GUID` as its value. But how should I calculate CLSID GUID? Are they predefined ? Exactly what value I need to assign ?

Step 2: Set the default value of the subkey to the string form of the object's class identifier (CLSID)GUID

```
The following example illustrates how to register an icon overlay handler 
named MyOverlay.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
  Software
    Microsoft
       Windows
          CurrentVersion
            Explorer
              ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers
                 MyOverlay
                 (Default) = {MyOverlay CLSID GUID}
```

Comment: You are asking for the chicken before laying the egg.  Write the code first, you'll know the guid.

Comment: I added random number as CLSID GUID and it is working. Is this correct way to do it ? I added this no as GUID : 58840846-AC99-4EDA-A80F-A7DBAFAC396E